# Golang Boolean not detecting on PATCH

Tags: go, boolean, go-gorm, go-fiber

I am and application where I am trying to indicate if a client is active or not.
If I manually set the ClientActive boolean to False, I can successfully convert it to True. But if it is True, it will not set to False.
I am using GoFiber and Gorm

models/Client.go

```
type Client struct {
gorm.Model
Slug           string `json:"slug" gorm:"unique"`
ClientName     string `json:"client_name"`
Address        string `json:"address,omitempty"`
Address2       string `json:"address_2,omitempty" gorm:"null"`
Phone          string `json:"phone" gorm:"null"`
PrimaryEmail   string `json:"primary_email" gorm:"null"`
SecondaryEmail string `json:"secondary_email" gorm:"null"`
ClientActive bool `json:"client_active" gorm:"default:true"`
Contacts     []Contact
Devices      []Device
}
```

handlers/clientHandler.go

```
func ClientUpdate(c \*fiber.Ctx) error {
slug := c.Params("slug")

    var data models.Client
    
    err := c.BodyParser(&data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    // todo: the ClientActive variable will set as true, but never false
    client := &models.Client{
        ClientName:     data.ClientName,
        Address:        data.Address,
        Address2:       data.Address2,
        Phone:          data.Phone,
        PrimaryEmail:   data.PrimaryEmail,
        SecondaryEmail: data.SecondaryEmail,
        ClientActive:   data.ClientActive,
    }
    
    err = database.DB.Model(&data).Where("slug = ?", slug).Updates(&client).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    return c.JSON(client)

}
```

All other lines update without issue. The only problem is the ClientActive boolean.

The full code is available at https://github.com/simpleittools/assetAPI

I have confirmed that the data is being sent as a boolean. I have run a fmt.Prtintln(client) both before and after the database input and it does show correctly as false.

I am getting no errors in the process.

Comment: by default the value is true. If I go into the database, and manually change the value to false, it will identify correctly on a GET request. If I send a PATCH where I set ClientActive to True, the column updates as expected.
But running a PATCH request where ClientActive = False, the column will remain True.
All other columns update as expected.

I tried by setting the Default to False, and then ran though the process of running a PATCH request to True. It will change to True. But then running again to set as False, results in no change.

So basically, once it is True, it stays True.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, thank you. This is resolved. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the correct solution.
Simply a pointer to the bool type in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GORM default values documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values) says:

> Any zero value like 0, '', false won’t be saved into the database for those fields defined default value, you might want to use pointer type or Scanner/Valuer to avoid this

Fix by changing the field type to `*bool`:

```
type Client struct {
    ⋮
    ClientActive *bool `json:"client_active" gorm:"default:true"`
    ⋮
}
```